# \rightbar using framed.sty only (without using mdframed and tcolorbox and tikz)

Tags: rules, framed

Is this possible to get `rightbar` same as `leftbar` by using `framed.sty`? I know this is possible by using `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`, but want to confirm is this possible by using `framed.sty` only?

PS: Hope `MWE` is not required for this (I can provide if requires)...

Please suggest...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I had no time to go though `framed` properly, so I might have missed some detail which makes this solution react unexpectedly in untested situations.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{rightbar}%
  {%
   \def\FrameCommand##1{##1\hspace{10pt}\vrule width 3pt}%
   \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}%
  }%
  {\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}

\begin{leftbar}
\lipsum[2]
\end{leftbar}

\begin{rightbar}
\lipsum[3]
\end{rightbar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You rock... Currently I'm not in system will check and get back to you shortly... Thanks a lot

Comment: It's works like a champ...Thanks a lot...